# Graph embedding spaces intermediate between 2D & 3D

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

The number of unlabeled connected *planar* graphs on $n$ nodes,
[A003094](http://oeis.org/A003094):
$$ 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 20, 99, 646, 5974, 71885, \ldots $$
is vastly smaller than the number of unlabled connected graphs on $n$ nodes,
[A001349](http://oeis.org/A001349):
$$ 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 21, 112, 853, 11117, 261080, \ldots $$

Planar graphs can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and *any* graph
can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (embedded $=$ without edge-edge intersections).
Both embeddings can be achieved by straight-line embeddings, but let's leave that aside.

I am wondering ...

> ***Q***. Are there intermediate spaces, preferably continuous intermediate spaces, that more gradually interpolate between 
>   few-graphs-in-$\mathbb{R}^2$ to all-graphs-in-$\mathbb{R}^3$?

Embedding on surfaces of genus $g>0$ is the only answer that occurs to me,
which gives a countable set of intermediates.
Is there some natural continuous analog?

Comment: You mean, with an uncountable set of intermediates?  So we would have to consider graphs with unbounded nodes?

Comment: @BrianTung: That's an interesting question, expanding in a different direction than I intended. I was more thinking of an uncountable set of intermediates, which gradually allow more and more graphs to be embedded, like a step function. The genus provides a rather crude step function, with large steps.

Comment: My point is that unless you consider unbounded graphs, how do you get an uncountable set of intermediates?  Are there an uncountable number of increasing sequences $A$ such that $A_{003094} < A < A_{001349}$, if we do not consider unbounded graphs?  (Upon further reflection, I'm not sure the answer is no, but it's worth asking.)

Comment: @BrianTung: We could have a continuous set of intermediates that allow---say---one more graph to be embedded at a countable number of thresholds. That is not the situation with genus.

Answer (score 1):

2D -- Grid graphs on a square grid.  All vertices must be on a grid point.  All edges are straight lines. No edges can pass through an occupied vertex. Edges may cross.

3D -- Grid graphs on a cubic grid. All vertices must be on a grid point. All edges are straight lines. No edges can cross or pass through an occupied vertex.

If the grids are infinite, you can get many graphs in either system.  By limiting the grids, the growth of the systems can be compared.  How many graphs can a 4x5 grid support, versus a 2x2x5 grid?

Comment: Interesting viewpoint, kinda tangent to the direction I was thinking, but alternative viewpoints are always illuminating.

Comment: I suppose my answer can be seen as "Look at $\mathbb{Z}^3$"